# Comparing values of two different cells evaluate to false - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new with JavaScript and I'm working on a Spreadsheet trying to hide a column base on the cell content.

The idea is: when value 1 and value 2 are the same (the value of two different cells are identical), the column stays as unhidden. When is not identical, it hides.  However, every time OnEdit, the columns hides regardless.

Also, I can't manage to make it unhide when the values are the same. Any ideas?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Auto media planner");      // Enter sheet name
  var cell1 = s.getRange('C7');
  var cell2 = s.getRange('AX6');
  var value1 = cell1.getValues();
  var value2 = cell2.getValues();
  var column = s.getRange("D1");

  if (value1!=value2){  
  s.hideColumn(column);
}
  

if (value1==value2){ 
  s.unhideColumn(column);
}
```

Comment: If it is a single cell use getValue not getValues ....... var value1 = cell1.getValue();
  var value2 = cell2.getValue();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- In your code, `value1` and `value2` are arrays with the following
  format `[[]]` because you use `getValues()`.
- You **can't** compare two **arrays** like you compare two values. This  `value1==value2` returns **false** even if the values inside the array are the same.
- To correctly compare two arrays, one way is to run: `JSON.stringify(value1)==JSON.stringify(value2)`
  and that will result in **true** if the value is the same.

**See this example:**

```js
val1 = [[0.0]];
val2 = [[0.0]];
  
console.log(val1 ==  val2) // Returns false
console.log(JSON.stringify(val1)==JSON.stringify(val2));  // Returns true
```

---

### Solution:

Just replace:

```
var value1 = cell1.getValues();
var value2 = cell2.getValues();
```

with:

```
var value1 = cell1.getValue();
var value2 = cell2.getValue();
```

**Here is the complete solution:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Auto media planner");      // Enter sheet name
  var cell1 = s.getRange('C7');
  var cell2 = s.getRange('AX6');
  var value1 = cell1.getValue();
  var value2 = cell2.getValue();
  var column = s.getRange("D1");

  if (value1!=value2){  
  s.hideColumn(column);
}
  

if (value1==value2){ 
  s.unhideColumn(column);
} 
}
```

Comment: It was a question of not picking up the array but rather the value of that single cell! Therefore removing the s from valueS was enough!! Well, that makes a lot of sense.  Often it's the tiniest thing that messes the whole thing up! :D Thanks a lot Marios!!!